# Creating excel formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, multiple-columns

From table I am attaching My requirement is to Return text "Full" or "Partial" or "None". "Full" if columns A,B and C includes text "Yes", "Partial" If column A,B and C includes 1 or more text "No", and return "None" If column A,B and C includes text "No".

[image]

I tried but getting wrong results because of multiple conditions. With one condition i was getting required result but not with many condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken then using <kbd>LOOKUP( )</kbd> Function with <kbd>COUNTIF( )</kbd> with wild card character `*` should work as well.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=LOOKUP(COUNTIF(A1:C1,"*Yes*"),{0,1,3},{"None","Partial","Full"})
```

---

Comment: Sure Mayukh, I would.

Comment: Really appreciate your quick response.

Comment: @Rajiv glad to know it worked out for you =)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(SUM(ISNUMBER(FIND("Yes",A1:C1))*1),"Partial","Partial","Full"),"None")
```

[image]

- `FIND("Yes",A1:C1)` will return the position in each cell that it finds Yes.  This will also find yes in things like "No, wasn't sorted Yesterday" - so be aware of that. If Yes isn't found a #VALUE! error is returned.
- `ISNUMBER()` returns TRUE if a number is returned, FALSE otherwise.
- `*1` turns the TRUE/FALSE into 1/0.
- `SUM` adds those 1/0's together.  Returning a value between 0 and 3.
- `CHOOSE` returns "Partial" if the number is 1 or 2 and Full if it's 3.  If it's 0 the CHOOSE functions returns an error, so is replaced with None.

**Edit:**  Is case sensitive, so won't find "yes".  Replace FIND with SEARCH if you want it non case-sensitive.

[image]

Comment: Hi Darren, I am sure your formula works however when i am copying your formula result showing "None" for some reason. Really appreciate your response.